# Dataloader CLI problems with mapping of CSV File

Tags: data-loader, data-migration, cli, dataloader-batch

I try to DELETE some Data from my Org.

I have written a process-conf.xml with 4 Beans which work in BulkApi Mode and a Windows Batch File which calls the Jobs:

- Job1) extract DATA from SF via SOQL "select Id from ObjectA__c" and write it to a CSV File "FileA.csv"
- Job2) DELETE the DATA with the just generated CSV "FileA.csv" using a Mappingfile "FileA.sdl"
- Job3) extract DATA from SF via SOQL "select Id from ObjectB__c" and write it to a CSV File "FileB.csv"
- Job4) DELETE the DATA with the just generated CSV "FileB.csv" using a Mappingfile "FileB.sdl"

The Content of the both Mappingfiles (FileA.sdl and FileB.sdl) are the same => ID=Id

Jobs 1 to 3 are working fine

When Dataloader starts with Job4 i got the "[INFO] ... Mapping for field ID will be ignored since destination column is empty" and the Deletion of the DATA fail

Automapping won't work either...

All Filepaths are correct. The CSV Files are generated by Dataloader itself. I made the Mappingfiles with the Dataloader GUI.

Can anyone give a hint why it won't work?

Thanks